# Geocomplete input within bootstrap dropdown - how to submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have link which activates dropdown menu, in this menu I have only one element - form with text input for location. I use http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/ on this input field to suggest location.

When I chose location from suggestion list, or when I type location and click `Enter` I'd like to have this form submited. Unfortunately it doesn't work this way, any idea how I could fix this?

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/ob1b7Lbe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Something like this ?*

**Js** :

```
$("input").geocomplete().bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
    $('form').submit();
  });
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/ob1b7Lbe/3/